# How did Geralt of Rivia escape the Wild Hunt

Tags: the-witcher

We know that he was a Wild Hunt rider, as he traded his soul for Yens', but how did he escape from the clutches of the Hunt. Does it relate to the 3rd game where the Hunt King says that Geralt brings more death and despair if left alone?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context what scene you are talking about? Is this from a short story or from one of the novels? What actually happened there and what is unclear to you?

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach it sounds like he's talking about the video game series; the backstory we learn in *Witcher 2* is that Geralt joined the Wild Hunt to save Yennefer's life, and somehow escaped and lost his memory just before the start of *Witcher 1*, and the Hunt is chasing him throughout the games. "How" was supposed to be explained in *Witcher 3* but I haven't played it yet.

Comment: @cahir, I am interested in all answers, books (if it applies) and games. The question is how did Gerald get out of the hunt, as we see him running from it in w2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Witcher 3, you will learn that

> Ciri freed Geralt from the wild hunt.  The intention of the Wild Hunt all along was to capture Ciri, they first tried to use Yennifer, and then they had Geralt for a while.  Once she freed him, she left him near Kaer Morhen to begin the events of Witcher 1.

Comment: Is that in the books too, or it's just in the games?

Comment: As I understand it, the games take place entirely _after_ the books; nothing from the games crosses back into the novels.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin  -  Geralt states a couple of times in games that he died once. This is precisely where the books ended *for him*.